# Copy(Not shallow or Deep) for structure in C/C++/Java equivalent. Copy to variable which is pointing to exactly the same memory for all members

Tags: java, c++, c, pointers, memory

Making copy of a variable for structure (having a pointer pointing to some variable, say, float and a normal variable integer) in C. Not shallow or deep Copy. but copy into a variable which is pointing to exactly the same memory.

Consider this code:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int value;
} Node;

void main()
{
    Node n1, n2, n3;

    char name[] = "This is the name";

    n1 = (Node){ name, 1337 };
    // HERE  n2 and n1 will contain name pointing to same memory location
    // But for value, they will have different memory location
    n2 = n1; 

    // Here n1 and n3 are referring to different memory locations for both name and value
    n3.value = n1.value;
    n3.name = strdup(n1.name); 

}
```

But I want some copy which is pointing to the same memory location for both name and value.

Is there a way in C or equivalent Java code or C++?
If it is in some other language please give your own example.

Comment: If you want something that *points* to some memory, use a *pointer* :-)

Comment: You have to do *either* shallow or deep copying, you can't do none (then you don't actually copy anything). If you just copy the pointer (i.e. `pointer1 = pointer2`) then you have shallow copying. Right now with your `strdup` call you have deep copying. If you just make a pointer or a reference to another structure, you're not actually copying at all.

Comment: And *what* language are you using? The three languages you tagged for the question are distinct and separate, and have differing concepts when it comes to copying.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, you're correct. I understand those 3 languages, so I was welcoming replies based on those 3 languages only.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can use references:

```
Node n1 = {name, 31337};
Node& n2 = n1;
```

and pointers:

```
Node n1 = {name, 31337};
Node* n2 = &n1;
```

In both cases, field `value` of `n1` and `n2` are on the same memory address.

in Java is just variable name assignation;

```
Node n1 = new Node(Name, 31337);
Node n2 = n1;
```

Variables `n1` and `n2` are references to the same object, and its members are identically the same.

Comment: Pardon me, i havent done C++ for a while, but i suspect `Node n1 = (Node){name, 31337};` is not valid C++?

Comment: No, the current standard (C++11) has *brace initialisation*, which is what is being used here.

Answer (score 0):

When you say,

```
Node n1, n2, n3;
```

Compiler creates different memories for 'name' and 'value' in stack.
As 'name' is a pointer, the memory it is pointing to is copied as per your wish but not the variable 'name'. Hence both 'name' and 'value' are different for n1, n2 and n3.

Even assignment(n2=n1) does not give same memory location for 'name' in both n1 and n2 but the memory 'name' is pointing to will be same.

And coming to your problem, this can achieved by using references and pointers as said by [vz0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209629/vz0)